# Whether Italian has the grammatical structure where you place a single adjective in a clause modifying something very distant

Tags: grammar

Take the following sentence:

> They threw him in prison, condemned.

'Condemned' modifies 'him', not 'prison' even though 'condemned' is closer to 'prison'.  Can you do something analogous in Italian such as:

> Lo hanno sbattuto in prigione, condannato.

By the way, I'm pretty sure that grammatical structure has some sort of name.  If anyone knows it, let me know so that I can change the title.

Comment: You can do that in Italian, and it is even easier sometimes than in English because of gender matching. In your phrase, "condannato" can only match "Lo" (him), not "prigione".

Comment: thanks, i appreciate that.

Comment: also, what about the comma, is the comma necessary? If it's not, then what if the two nouns are the same in gender and in number?

Comment: No, this doesn't sound right. If anything, it could be something one writes in a telegram or in an awkwardly phased newspaper title.

Comment: With an "e" it's a bit better "Lo hanno rinchiuso in prigione e (poi) condannato". By the way, you mostly "consegni" a package, rarely a person.

Comment: We'll change it to 'sbattuto'.  I'm not worried with how best to express the thought, I'm worried about whether or not the syntax is legal.

Comment: No, it isn't. If someone thinks differently, I'd be grateful if they showed some source or example from actual Italian texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to your sentence:

```
 They threw him in prison, condemned.
```

Yes, you can say in Italian:

```
Lo hanno sbattuto in prigione, condannato.
```

This sentence is composed of two clauses: the main clause "Lo hanno sbattuto in prigione" and the subordinate clause "condannato".

The main clause is in the perfect tense, composed of the auxiliary verb "avere" (hanno) and the past participle "sbattuto". The subject of this clause is the pronoun "lo".

The subordinate clause is in the past tense, composed of the verb "condannare" (condannato). This clause is used to provide additional information about the main clause.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147550/discussion-on-answer-by-luca-spuntoni-whether-italian-has-the-grammatical-struct); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score -1):

No, a sentence like *Lo hanno sbattuto in prigione, condannato*, even if understandable, sounds quite clunky. It might be something that appears in a newspaper title, where due to the lack of a space they have to omit parts of a sentence. A more natural phrasing would be *Lo hanno sbattuto in prigione e condannato* if you mean that the condemn happened after the imprisonment (or did they jail him after condemning him? that phrasing isn't even clear about this).

The position that *condannato* occupies in this sentence might be more plausible for a word or clause that agrees with the subject of the sentence rather than, as here, with its object. So, for instance, one might say *lo hanno sbattuto in prigione, inflessibili*. It would be even better if the last part were something more similar to a subordinate clause, as in

> lo hanno sbattuto in prigione, incuranti dei suoi diritti

or

> lo hanno sbattuto in prigione, sordi alle sue lamentele.